# C++ Seek a std::string::iterator to given position

Tags: c++, string, iterator, seek

Is it possible to seek a `std::string::iterator` safely to a given position?

std::string::iterator has a offset access operator (operator []), but it exists in the category defined by some people as undefined behavior, like `it + 3`.

[cplusplus.com reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/)

Comment: can you explain better your question? and what do you mean with *safely*?

Comment: Who says that `it + 3` has undefined behaviour? They are wrong (apart from in the case where the iteration goes past the end of the string).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> std::string::iterator has a offset access operator (operator []), but it exists in the category defined by some people as undefined behavior, like it + 3.

I don’t understand this statement. There is no such category. `std::basic_string<>::iterator` is a random access iterator and as such you can seek by just adding or subtracting an offset to / from it (which is consistent with the documentation you linked to):

```
auto new_it = it + offset;
```

What’s undefined is seeking past the `end()` iterator of the associated container, or before its beginning. That is, the following is undefined behaviour:

```
std::string str = "hi";
auto it1 = str.begin() + 2; // OK.
assert(it1 == str.end());
auto it2 = str.begin() + 3; // UB!
// At this point we cannot assert anything about it2
```

Comment: Thanks for solution (correcting me)! Haha you make me feel pretty stupid.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know where you got the idea that `operator[]` is UB for `std::string::iterator`. It's defined as a random-access iterator, which supports `i[n]` as well as `i + n`.

Based on comments elsewhere, it appears you are after absolute positioning (That isn't very clear from the wording of your question). You can't do that from an iterator who's position you don't know, but you can achieve the same effect by offsetting relative to the iterator returned by `begin()`, i.e.: `str.begin()[3]` or `str.begin() + 3`. If you don't have the original string handy, you're hosed.

Answer (score 1):

Standard iterators are specified in such a way that they don't need to refer to the container (or other sequence) that they iterator over; this means that there is no way to do an "absolute seek" using just an iterator. You will need get a new iterator from the string, checking yourself that it's in range; something like:

```
std::string::iterator seek(std::string & s, size_t i) {
    return s.length() <= i ? s.end() : s.begin() + i;
}
```

Arithmetic on random-access iterators, and `operator[]` on strings, are well-defined as long as you stay within range. Behaviour is only undefined if you go out of range.